# Initial register value in synthesized design is always 0

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga, register, synthesis

I'm using Altera Cyclone IV EP4CE6 as my FPGA.
Compiling the design in Quartus Prime 18.0.0 Lite Edition.

The `State` register in the below module appears to be 0 initially even if I specify a different default value (I.e. if I set `ST_INITIALWAIT` to anything but 0 it doesn't work).

I've tried specifying the default value inline with the definition and in an initial block.

**Non-zero initial register values work fine in other modules in the same design, so I'm puzzled why it doesn't in this module.**

```
module CamSetup(clk, ready, error, scl, sda);
input clk;
output ready, error;
output scl;
inout sda;

parameter ST_READY = 4'd1;
parameter ST_WRITING = 4'd2;
parameter ST_ENDING = 4'd3;
parameter ST_INTERIM = 4'd4;
parameter ST_INITIALWAIT = 4'd0;

parameter REG_COUNT = 1;

//truncated to save space (actually updates 170 registers)
bit [1:REG_COUNT][0:2][7:0] RegValues = {
    8'h42, 8'h7a, 8'h20 
};

parameter CLKS_INIT = 10;
parameter CLKS_INTERIM = 50000;

reg [23:0] InitiCounter = 0;
reg [23:0] InterimCounter = 0;

reg [3:0] State = ST_INITIALWAIT;
reg [7:0] RegIndex  = 0;
reg [2:0] RegByteIndex  = 0;
reg [7:0] WrData = 0;

wire WrDataRq;
wire I2cIdle;
wire Enable = (State == ST_WRITING);
assign ready = (State == ST_READY);


i2c i2c0(.clk(clk), .enable(Enable), .wr_data(WrData), .wr_data_rq(WrDataRq), .idle(I2cIdle), .error(error), .scl(scl), .sda(sda));

always @(posedge clk)
begin

    case(State)

    ST_INITIALWAIT:
    begin
        InitiCounter <= InitiCounter + 1;

        if(InitiCounter >= CLKS_INIT)
        begin
            State <= ST_ENDING;
        end     
    end

    ST_ENDING:
    begin
        if(I2cIdle)
        begin           
            if(RegIndex < REG_COUNT)
            begin
                RegIndex <= RegIndex + 1;
                RegByteIndex <= 0;              
                WrData <= RegValues[RegIndex+1][0];
                State <= ST_INTERIM;
            end
            else
            begin
                State <= ST_READY;
            end         
        end
    end

    ST_INTERIM:
    begin
        InterimCounter <= InterimCounter + 1;

        if(InterimCounter >= CLKS_INTERIM)
        begin
            InterimCounter <= 0;
            State <= ST_WRITING;
        end
    end

    ST_WRITING:
    if(WrDataRq)
    begin       
        if(RegByteIndex < 2)
        begin
            RegByteIndex <= RegByteIndex + 1;
            WrData <= RegValues[RegIndex][RegByteIndex+1];
        end
        else
        begin
            State <= ST_ENDING;
        end
    end         

    endcase

end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Quartus, the initial value in a declaration only works for simulation. For Synthesis (and simulation), you need to use a separate initial block.

```
initial begin
    State = non_zero_state;
    ...
```

Comment: Tried both the initial block and the inline. The inline works just fine in other modules in the same design.

Comment: Then for a state machine, you may need a reset.

Comment: I've made the initial state 0 and it works fine, just curious why the non-zero values didn't work in this case.

Comment: Like I said, for registers recognized as FSM state variables, you need an explicit reset to get a value other than 0 as an initial state